# ruby shoes "illegal instruction" macbook air but not on imac ( ./pango-querymodules?)

Tags: ruby, shoes, pango

Everything going well, building ruby-shoes app on imac. Attempt to dev/run packaged app on my air get illegal instruction.

- only happens with latest shoes version (federalas). seems to be ok on policeman
- checked the architecture / file type - identical on both machines (e.g. x86_64)
- seems to be ./pango-querymodules that causes the first illegal instruction
- both machines OSX Yosemite (10.10.3)
- attempted to install shoes from scratch and also tried to copy over from working imac version

has anyone seen this? I need to start digging into all files md5, libraries etc, but thought i'd ask the question before i embark

thanks

*Output/Data*

```
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/shoes-launch myapp.rb
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/shoes-launch: line 8: 57221 Illegal instruction: 4  PANGO_RC_FILE="$APPPATH/pangorc" ./pango-querymodules > pango.modules
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/shoes-launch: line 9: 57503 Illegal instruction: 4  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$APPPATH" PANGO_RC_FILE="$APPPATH/pangorc" SHOES_RUBY_ARCH="x86_64-darwin14.0" ./shoes-bin "$@"
```

File type of program with illegal instruction

```
$ file /Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/pango-querymodules 
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/pango-querymodules: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: I believe pango-querymodules  is a python tool?